# Need Help Creating 2 linked Lists and then reassigning them to reorder the nodes

Tags: c#, linked-list

I am a student in school and really need some help understanding how to implement a linked list and add Node objects and then rearrange them into a different order by reassigning their references. I am struggling to understand this topic and have looked extensively online without any luck finding a good detailed walk through of what to do. I have included the three scenarios that I need to solve and would truly appreciate some help understanding what to do in these scenarios so I can practice it on my own. Many thanks in advance for anyone that can help!!!

Write code to solve the following LinkedList Mystery Problems

NOTE: / means NULL i.e. end of list

## 1. Write the code necessary to convert the following sequences of ListNode objects:

list ---> [1] ---> [2] ---> [3] /

temp ---> [4] ---> [5] ---> [6] /

into this sequence of ListNode Objects:

list ---> [5] ---> [3] ---> [4] ---> [2] /

## 2.Write the code necessary to convert the following sequences of ListNode objects:

list ---> [1] ---> [2] ---> [3] ---> [4] /

into this sequence of ListNode Objects:

list1 ---> [4] ---> [2] /

list2 ---> [3] ---> [1] /

## 3.Write the code necessary to convert the following sequences of ListNode objects:

list1 ---> [1] /

list2 ---> [2] ---> [3] ---> [4] /

into this sequence of ListNode Objects:

list1 ---> [4] ---> [1] ---> [2]

list2 ---> [3] /

This is what I have so far for the first questions but know it isn't right and feel like I am spinning my wheels trying to understand what I am doing wrong.....

'''

> Blockquote

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace Mini_Assigment_1
    {
    
        class Node
        {
            public int data;
            public Node next;
    
            public Node()
            {
                this.data = 0;
                this.next = null;
            }
    
            public Node(int data)
            {
                this.data = data;
                this.next = null;
            }
    
            public Node(int data, Node next)
            {
                this.data = data;
                this.next = next;
            }
    
            public Node Add(int data)
            {
                Node node = new Node(data);
                if (this.next == null)
                {
                    node.next = null;
                    this.next = node;
                }
                else
                {
                    Node temp = this.next;
                    node.next = temp;
                    this.next = node;
                }
                return node;
            }
        }
        
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                LinkedList<int> list1 = new LinkedList<int>();
                list1.AddLast(1);
                list1.AddLast(2);
                list1.AddLast(3);
    
                LinkedList<int> list2 = new LinkedList<int>();
                list2.AddLast(4);
                list2.AddLast(5);
                list2.AddLast(6);
                 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Start coding after looking [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: This question is far too broad. Stack Overflow is not a suitable place for general, open-ended discussions that would be required to deal with students who are floundering. That jobs rests squarely on the shoulders of your teacher. If you want help here, you'll need to focus on one _specific_ problem at a time, providing a good [mcve] that shows what you've tried, explain what _specific_ thing that code is supposed to do, and what exactly it is about the code that you still can't figure out. See also [ask] for info on how to present a clear, answerable question.